# How to use checkbox with nested ng-repeat in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, checkbox

**Hello everyone** i have faced some problem in case of nested checkbox uses. In my problem i m stuck on to how to use IncludeAll on click checkbox. If checkbox value is true then it's give me a value of that. if IncludeAll checkbox is true then all checkbox will be selected and show the value of all in **Array**. and if one of the checkbox is false then IncludeAll checkbox false..**But in Case the other checkbox will be selected**.

**This is my Fiddle Link :**  http://jsfiddle.net/0x4396pu/1/

**Here is my Html Code:**

```
 <form action="#" ng-controller='MyCtrl'>
     <div class="control-group" ng-repeat="story in stories">
     <br>
     <input type="checkbox" ng-model="story.selectionAll">
        <label class="control-label">IncludeAll {{story}}</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <label class="checkbox inline" ng-repeat="browser in browsers">
                <input type="checkbox" value="{{browser}}"  
                   ng-model="selection[story].browsers[browser]"
                   ng-checked="story.selectionAll"> 
               {{browser}}
           </label>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
<pre>{{selection | json }}</pre>
</form>
```

**Here is my Controller file :**

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.stories = ['1', '2', '3'];
  $scope.browsers = ['IE', 'Chrome', 'Firefox','Safari','Opera'];
  $scope.selection = {};
  angular.forEach($scope.stories, function(story) {
     $scope.selection[story] = {
       browsers: {},
     };
  });
}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I am answer my own Question. But anyway Here is Answer how to select Checkbox in Nested ng-repeat.i think It's Help you Thanks.**

**Http Plunkr LInk**  http://plnkr.co/edit/OQxi53xtVKOgToPhzDUZ?p=preview

**Here is Html Code:**

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.4
        /angular.min.js">
      </script>
     <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
  <form action="#" ng-controller='detailContrller'>
   <div class="control-group" ng-repeat="story in stories"> <br>
      <h4> Enter Data </h4>
             Name :  <input type="text" data-ng-model="selection[story].Name1" 
                        placeholder="Enter Name">  <br>
          Address :  <input type="text" data-ng-model="selection[story].Name2" 
                        placeholder="Enter Address">  <br>
          City :    <input type="text" data-ng-model="selection[story].Name3"
                        placeholder="Enter City">  <br>
          Phone :  <input type="text" data-ng-model="selection[story].Name4" 
                        placeholder="Enter Phone ">  <br>
          State :  <input type="text" data-ng-model="selection[story].Name5" 
                        placeholder="Enter State">  <br>

    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selection[story].all"
            ng-change="updateAll(story)">
    <label class="control-label">IncludeAll {{story}}</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <label class="checkbox inline" ng-repeat="browser in browsers">
                <input type="checkbox" value="{{browser}}"
                 ng-model="selection[story].browsers[browser]" 
                   ng-change="checkChange(browser)"
                > {{browser}}
                </label>
            </div>
    </div>
      <button type="button" data-ng-click="save()">Save</button>
      <pre>{{selection | json}}</pre>
    </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

**Here is my Controller**

```
var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);

app.controller('detailContrller', function($scope){

$scope.stories = [];
$scope.browsers = ['IE', 'Chrome', 'Firefox','Safari','Opera'];
$scope.selection = {};
$scope.details = {};

 var checked;
 $scope.updateAll = function (story) {
    checked = $scope.selection[story].all;
    $scope.browsers.forEach(function (browser) {
        $scope.selection[story].browsers[browser] = checked;
    });
 };

 for(var i = 0; i< 3; i++) {
  $scope.stories.push(i+1);
 }
  $scope.checkChange = function (browser) {
    for(var i =0; i< $scope.stories.length; i++){
        if(!$scope.stories[i].selected){
        checked = false
        return false;
        }
     }
  }
    angular.forEach($scope.stories, function(storgy) {
       $scope.selection[storgy] = {
        browsers: {}
      };
    });

  $scope.save = function () {
   console.log($scope.selection);
  }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Your "include all" checkbox is trying to set `.selectionAll` property on a `String` (`story in stories` gives you a `String`).
2. You can't use `ng-checked` to somehow "work together" with `ng-model`. If you want your "include all" checkbox to select all subordinate checkboxes and vice versa, you'll need to watch the changes and provide some logic connecting the two things in your controller.

---

For example, if you want change of the "include all" checkbox value to influence other checkboxes, you'd have to do something like

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="selection[story].all" ng-change="updateAll(story)">
```

and in your controller

```
$scope.updateAll = function (story) {
    var checked = $scope.selection[story].all;
    $scope.browsers.forEach(function (browser) {
        $scope.selection[story].browsers[browser] = checked;
    });
};
```

and handle changes of the individual checkboxes in a similar fashion.

Comment: hey #hon2a can you help me more..by explain it in example in fiddle or plunkr.

Comment: Hey #hon2a i have check this and It's working Fine. Thanks for Explanation In Detail.